# How to check if an image has been annotated?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

I have an image box to display 1 image at a time and the option to annotate these images. Now I want to save only those images that have been annotated or modified. How to achieve this?

What I have tried:

Wanted to play with the option of using the mouse down , drag and release events to see which images have been touched and save only those images. tried to utilize the option of finding difference in image file sizes.. but that was not much helpfull

Comment: _ annotated or modified_ Do you know what that can mean? Can you tell us??

Comment: I basically have a canvas to display an image and options to annotate the image(draw, type text etc.) and then save it. So I want to save only those images that have been annotated ..

Comment: compare the images - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39980/determining-if-2-images-are-the-same

Comment: You could set a few special pixels to a special value and test for those. Make sure your marker is robust enough for your file format..!

Answer (score 0):

After you call the annotate function just set an attribute on the image to highlight this. When you want to save, just loop all the images and check this attribute.

```
<img src="smiley.gif" data-annotate="true" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
```